# Memorizing mysql query with rand in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, session

```
$query= "select * from table ORDER BY RAND()" ;
$result = mysql_query($query); 
if(!isset($_get['submit']))
    $_SESSION['a']=$result;
else 
    $result=$_SESSION['a'] ;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row["names"];
}
echo "<input name='submit' type='submit' value='Submit'>";
```

This is not all the code of course, but the problem is here:

So 1st my page opens up with names in random order (ex. John Dan Mary)

and after submitting the form (taking me to the same page) , it either (depending on the solutions I tried ) lists the names in different random order (Dan Mary John) or I get this error :

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, 
integer(or array) given in C:\wamp...
```

I want after submitting the form the names to remain in the pre-submitted order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result from `mysql_query` is not cachable in the way you intend to do it. What you will need to do is to loop through the rows like such:

```
$row = array();
while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($row)) {
   $row[] = $r;
}
$_SESSION['rows'] = $row;
```

Which will then pass nicely in the session and be re-usable.

In addition to this, `table` is a reserved keyword. Use backticks to escape it.

If you want the technical reason, the return from `mysql_query` is actually a MySQL resource indicator, which is an integer. Every new script instance, these are reset. This is why it is failing.

P.S: ORDER BY RAND() is extremely poor on performance. Look up alternatives!

Answer (score 1):

If your mysql tablename is "table" then you are using reserved keyword as tablename use backtick operator

```
$query= "select * from `table` ORDER BY RAND()" ;
```

Comment: its not, just named it so here without thinking straight, but thanks for the input

Answer (score 0):

The script isn't memorizing the order, its memorizing the query recordset. So the rand() function is going to reload each time.

```
if(!isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
{
    $query= "select * from table ORDER BY RAND()" ;
    $result = mysql_query($query); 

    $names = array();

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        $names[] = $row['name'];
    }

    $_SESSION['names'] = serialize($names);
}

echo implode(', ', unserialize($_SESSION['names']));
echo "<input name='submit' type='submit' value='Submit'>";
```

You should generate the random order of names, save it to a session, then use the session to output the names instead of the query

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is when you don't have any results returned, but you are trying to extract the results anyway. You  should be checking your result set using mysql_num_rows before trying to fetch the results.

If you want the results to come back in the order they were submitted to the database I suggest ordering by the primary key (assuming you use a user_id or other ID as your primary key).